How does the robotic octopus arm work?
I have seen many articles about it but none describe the action mechanism. Do they use a pneumatic actuators or do they use some kind of electroactive polymers that contract similar to the muscles in an octopus arm?

There are many robotic octopus-like projects. If you want people to comment on a specific one, please provide a link to what you've seen.

your question is similar to how is rope made?
